# React function prop gives "TypeError is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I am new to react and I'm trying to pass a function as a prop to a child component.
In my case this is the parent component:

```
export default function Game() {
const [gameStarted, setGameStarted] = useState(false)
const [gameSettings, setGameSettings] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
  //setGameStarted(true);
  }, [gameSettings]
)
  
return (
  <>
  {!gameStarted && 
    <div className="game-form">
      <GameSelection handleGameSelection={(settings)=> setGameSettings(settings)}/>
    </div>}
  </>
  )}
```

My child component is:

```
export default function GameSelection({handleGameSelection}) {
const [labels, setLabels] = useState([])
const [gameMode, setGameMode] = useState('')
const [selectedLabels, setSelectedLabels] = useState([])
const [formError, setFormError] = useState(null)

// create label values for react-select
useEffect(() => {
    if(document) {
      setLabels(document.cards.map(card => {
        return { value: {...card}, label: card.label}
      }))
    }
  }, [document])


const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  try{
    const gameSettings = {
      mode: gameMode.value,
      selected: selectedLabels.map((card) => ({...card.value})),
    }
    handleGameSelection(gameSettings)
  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}

return (
    <>
        <h2 className="page-title">Please select your game</h2>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label>
              <span>Mode:</span>
                  <Select
                      onChange={(option) => setGameMode(option)}
                      options={gameModes}
                  />
          </label>
          <label>
              <span>Select labels:</span>
                  <Select
                      onChange={(option) => setSelectedLabels(option)}
                      options={labels}
                      isMulti
                  />
          </label>
          
          <button className="btn" >Start game</button>
  
          {formError && <p className="error">{formError}</p>}
          </form>
    </>
  )}
```

My form works but when I submit the form I keep getting the error TypeError: handleGameSelection is not a function. I tried everything. I have created a separate function in the parent component and gave that as a prop to the child. That also didn't work. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Run this function inside useEffect, because currently, you are running this function before component is fully mounted and this function is propably undefined... or you can try to use `if(typeof handleGameSelection === 'function')` to check if its already initialized

Comment: You're right. When i check the type of handleGameSelection it says "undefined". Now i tried try to run the function in useEffect but i still get the error. Maybe i'm doing it wrong.. How should i run it in useEffect?

Comment: oh sorry, i misslooked and i thought its not in handleSubmit. iwould just try to typcheck this